# Always getting nil in completion

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get `Map data` I have in `Firestore`, this is how it looks:
[image]

I'm trying to get the data, and create an array of `Friend Object` and return the `array` in the `completion handler`.

This is what I have:

```
func fetchFriendList(_ id: String, completion: @escaping([Friend]?)->()) {
    var fetchedFriends: [Friend]?
    db.collection(USERS_COLLECTION).document(id).getDocument { (doc, err) in
        if err == nil && doc != nil {
            guard let results = doc?.data()?[USER_FOLLOWING] as? [String: Any] else { return }
            for result in results { // Getting the data in firebase
                if let resultValue = result.value as? [String: Any] { // Getting only the value of the MAP data, we do not need the key.

                    //Getting the fields from the result
                    guard let id = resultValue[FRIEND_ID] as? String else { return }
                    guard let profilePic = resultValue[FRIEND_PROFILE_PIC] as? String else { return }
                    guard let username = resultValue[FRIEND_NAME] as? String else { return }
                    guard let email = resultValue[FRIEND_MAIL] as? String else { return }

                    //Creating a new Friend object from the fields
                    let friend = Friend(id: id, profilePicture: profilePic, username: username, email: email)
                    fetchedFriends?.append(friend)
                }
                completion(fetchedFriends)
            }
        }else {
            print(err!.localizedDescription)
            completion(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

I tried printing the results, and resultValue etc, they are not nil.
But, after trying to append and print the fetchedFriends Array, I get nil, and the completion is also nil.
I don't really understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't initialized variable **fetchedFriends** and you have used optional type when appending data to it. Since it has not been initialized, it will skip appending to it. You should initialize it in the beginning. The updated code would be as follows.

```
func fetchFriendList(_ id: String, completion: @escaping([Friend]?)->()) {
    var fetchedFriends: [Friend] = []
    db.collection(USERS_COLLECTION).document(id).getDocument { (doc, err) in
        if err == nil && doc != nil {
            guard let results = doc?.data()?[USER_FOLLOWING] as? [String: Any] else { return }
            for result in results { // Getting the data in firebase
                if let resultValue = result.value as? [String: Any] { // Getting only the value of the MAP data, we do not need the key.

                    //Getting the fields from the result
                    guard let id = resultValue[FRIEND_ID] as? String else { return }
                    guard let profilePic = resultValue[FRIEND_PROFILE_PIC] as? String else { return }
                    guard let username = resultValue[FRIEND_NAME] as? String else { return }
                    guard let email = resultValue[FRIEND_MAIL] as? String else { return }

                    //Creating a new Friend object from the fields
                    let friend = Friend(id: id, profilePicture: profilePic, username: username, email: email)
                    fetchedFriends.append(friend)
                }
                completion(fetchedFriends)
            }
        }else {
            print(err!.localizedDescription)
            completion(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.